# Recover user of creation and last modification

Tags: python, django

I have a model using `TimeStampedModel` where created and updated is already integrated

```
class Universo(TimeStampedModel):
    nombre = models.CharField('Universo', max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Universo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Universos'
        ordering = ['nombre']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

In the administrator view indicate the user who created and modified it
[Image Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG3xK.png)

In template I can call its attributes with

```
{{u}} {{u.created}} {{u.modified}}
```

But I can't find how to bring the user I think I have made the modification to the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a bit more to achieve what you want. I'll give the starting point:

You must first establish a relationship between your Universo model and Django user model.

```
from django.auth.models import User:

class Universo(TimeStampedModel):
    nombre = models.CharField('Universo', max_length=10)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Universo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Universos'
        ordering = ['nombre']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

You can use the admin login to use your `superuser` as the logged-in user. But, in your views, you need to include the logged-in user (from `request.user`) in the creation of the instance for your `Univeso` model.

Then, in your template, you can render who has created it by doing this:

```
{{ u.created_by }}
```

you can further probe the fields of `created_by`:

```
{{u.created_by.name}}
```

Comment: Adding the user in the model allows me in the admin panel to select who creates or modifies it, when using request.user in the template it shows me the user that is connected, I would need to show the users who made the creation or modification

Comment: @ErickLópez I updated the answer. It's as easy as doing this: `{{ u.created_by }}`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your template like this:

```
{{u}} {{u.created}} {{u.modified}} {{u.created_by.username}}
```

You can use another of the fields like username,email or any other

This should give the user that modified it.

Comment: it only shows me the user that is connected at that moment